# Can I use Karate UI to get the current scroll position of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, karate

I'm trying use Karate UI to test a button that scrolls to the top of the page when clicked, but I can't find a way to get the scroll position with JavaScript in order to validate the scrolling has occurred.

I am able to scroll the document with the line `* script('window.scrollTo(0,1000)')` but if I try to get the position with

```
* def getPosition = function(){return window.scrollY}
* def ypos = getPosition()
```

I get the error message `Reference Error: "window" is not defined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
* def getPosition = function(){ return script('window.scrollY') }
```

Refer this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser